# Access One WindowsForm label to another form in C#

Tags: c#, .net, argumentnullexception, windowsformsintegration

I am using two windows form application, and I want to set 1st form label's value from 2nd form. 
But when I access 1st form label in 2nd form then application show this error

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

I am using this statement to access

```
login_form.ActiveForm.Controls["label_name"].Text = "Hello World";
```

sometime i worked fine but some time show this error

Please solve my problem. I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: something here is null. could be `login_form`, could be `ActiveForm`, could be `Controls["label_name"]`. Use debugger to find out what it is

Comment: -login_form.ActiveForm null System.Windows.Forms.Form

Comment: Active Form value is null

Comment: why do you need the `ActiveForm` property? did you try `login_form.Controls["label_name"]`?

Comment: login_form.Controls["label_name"].Text = "Hello World";
i showed red line below controls

Comment: [ActiveForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activeform.aspx) returns **a Form that represents the currently active form, or null if there is no active form**.

Answer (score 1):

You would be wise to either:

1. Expose a property in the first form through which you can enact a change to the label text.
2. Expose a method in the first form that you can call to affect a label text change.

Example #1:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    public String LabelText
    {
        get { return label_name.Text; }
        set { label_name.Text = value; }
    }
}

//from Form2...
login_form.LabelText = "Hello World";
```

Example #2:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    public void SetLabelText(String TextToSet)
    {
        label_name.Text = TextToSet;
    }
}

//from Form2...
login_form.SetLabelText("Hello World");
```

I would not advise simply changing the control to be `Public`.  Indirect access is preferable.